# Group by in Dataframe using numeric elements Usining Spark Scala

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a Hive query which I need to convert it into Dataframe. The query is as below

```sql
select sum(col1),max(col2) from table 
group by 3,4,5,1,2,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24;
```

I don't know how do I do that in Dataframe, generally we use

```
df.groupBy(columnName).agg()
```

But how can I convert the above query to Spark Dataframe.

Comment: what are `3,4,5,1,2,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24`? column names or column indexes?

Comment: Column indexes,the query is selecting more than 24 columns

Comment: may be we can do that in hive I guess,not sure about dataframe

Comment: update the question if you want it in scala or python or any other platform?

Comment: done updated,I need that in spark scala

Comment: I have answered below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can simply *select* the *column names* from *array of columns* (`df.columns`) using the *indexes* and then use those *selected column names* in `groupBy` and use *aggregation function***.

So the complete translation would be

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val groupingIndexes = Seq(3,4,5,1,2,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24)
df.groupBy(groupingIndexes.map(x => df.columns(x)).map(col): _*).agg(sum("col1"),max("col2"))
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
val df = spark.table("tablename")    
df.groupBy(lit(1), lit(2), lit(5),... ,lit(24)).agg(sum(col("col1")).as("sumval"), max(col("col2")).as("maxval")).select("maxval","sumval")
```

Thanks
Ravi

Comment: he is not grouping by columns , but numeric elements like 1,2,3.I dont know that part

Comment: Thanks Ravi ,That helped too